# Error "unresolved external symbol" when library is dynamically loaded at runtime

Tags: c++, windows, dll, cmake, loading

I have a big project where an executable `A.exe` is generated (with a cmake toolchain) to dynamically load `B.dll` **at run-time**. But without compile-time linking with `B.dll`, I got "unresolved external symbol" when building the executable.

The project organized like this:

`superproject
  |
  |--- build/
  |----CMakeLists.txt
  |--- src/
       |
       |---a : a1.cpp, CMakeLists.txt
       |---b : b.h, b.cpp, export.def, CMakeLists.txt`

file **src/b/b.h**:

```
class Machine
{
    int u;
    static Machine* sing;
public:
    Machine();
    static Machine* GetInstance();
    int answer();
};
```

file **src/b/b.cpp**:

```
#include "b.h"

Machine* Machine::sing;

Machine::Machine() : u(1) {}

Machine* Machine::GetInstance()
{
   if (!sing)
      sing = new Machine();
   return sing;
}

int Machine::answer(){ return u + 33; }

Machine* GetMach()
{
   return Machine::GetInstance();
}
```

file **src/a/a1.cpp**:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "b.h"

using namespace std;
typedef Machine* (*func_t)();
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   cout << "hello\n";
   HMODULE lib = LoadLibrary("b.dll");
   if (lib)
   {
      void* rawfunc = GetProcAddress(lib, "GetMach");
      if (rawfunc)
      {
         func_t func = (func_t)(rawfunc);
         Machine* m = func();
         cout << "The exported number is " << m->answer();
      }
      else
      {
         cout << "Failed to get the symbol";
      }
   }
   else
   {
      cout << "Failed to load library";
   }
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

file **src/b/export.def**:

```
EXPORTS
    GetMach
```

file **src/b/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_FILES *.cpp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE DEF_FILES *.def)
add_library(b MODULE ${SRC_FILES} ${DEF_FILES})
```

file **src/a/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_FILES *)
include_directories(../b)
add_executable(A ${SRC_FILES})
```

Visual Studio complains of:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __cdecl Machine::answer(void)" (?answer@Machine@@QEAAHXZ) referenced in function main    C:\....\superproj\build\a\a1.obj    A
```

Why have I got this error and how to eliminate it?

Comment: You don't need any link between `A.exe` and `B.dll` (and their targets). As for "undefined symbols" in `B.dll`, they should be defined  either in (other) library, linked into `B`: `target_link_libraries(B C)`, or by `A` executable or by a library linked into it: `target_link_libraries(A D)`. Note, that symbols provided by `A` for use in a dynamically loaded library `B` should be marked appropriately for that purpose (with `dllexport` or so).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Ok I did this but sorry the messages are "unresolved external symbols" (error LNK2019) maybe it is different?

Comment: As for `Machine::answer` method, it should be exported from `B` library and imported by `A` executable for being usable by `A`. Alternatively, you may declare the method as `virtual`, so `A` will resolve it at **runtime**, extracting it from `Machine` instance obtained from `func()` call. This is how I exported a class in my usage of dynamically-loaded library.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you very much!! It works when declaring`virtual`. Maybe you want to make these comments into an answer?

Comment: I have slighlty reformulated the question, so it could be useful for futher readers. If you think I have removed the meaningfull details, feel free for edit that. Also, you may delete your comments, which are currently incorporated into the questions post itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the linker's point of view, *non-virtual* method (`Machine::answer`) is the same as global function (say, `GetMach()`).

That is, for being able to use this method, `A` should either:

- link (`target_link_libraries`) with a library defining the method or
- request the method at *runtime* (`GetProcAddress()`).

If both of these approaches seems inconvinent, you may declare the method as *virtual*:

```
virtual int answer();
```

All *virtual* methods are resolved **at runtime**. A linker doesn't bother about using of virtual methods.